# Java JPA Unit Test saving 2 items

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss-arquillian

I have a simple `@OneToMany` setup with 2 entities - `Item` and `Group`, and am having an interesting problem.  When my integration test creates a `Group`, adds an `Item` to it and saves the `Group`, 2 instances of the `Item` end up getting saved.  Any ideas why?  I'm using Hibernate, if it matters:

> The **Item** entity

```
@Entity
public class NamedEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    Long             id;

    @NotNull
    String           name;

    NamedEntityGroup namedEntityGroup;

    NamedEntityType  type;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public NamedEntityType getType() { return type; }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    @JoinColumn(name = "NamedEntityGroupId")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public NamedEntityGroup getNamedEntityGroup() { return  this.namedEntityGroup; }
}
```

> The **Group** entity

```
    @Entity
    public class NamedEntityGroup implements Serializable {
        Long              id;

        String            name;

        List<NamedEntity> namedEntities;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public Long getId() { return this.id; }

        public String getName() { return this.name; }

        @JsonManagedReference
        @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "namedEntityGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        public List<NamedEntity> getNamedEntities() { return this.namedEntities; }

        public void addNamedEntity(NamedEntity ne) {
            if (this.namedEntities == null) {
                this.namedEntities = new ArrayList<NamedEntity>();
            }
            if (!namedEntities.contains(ne)) {
                this.namedEntities.add(ne);
            }
            ne.setNEG(this);
        }
    }
```

> The **DAO** class

```
    public void save(NamedEntity ne) throws EntityValidationException {
        validate(ne);
        if(ne.getNamedEntityGroup() != null) {
            if(!em.contains(ne.getNamedEntityGroup())) {
                ne.setNamedEntityGroup(em.merge(ne.getNamedEntityGroup()));
                em.persist(ne);
                return;
            }
        } 

        em.persist(ne); 
    }
```

> The **test** method

```
    @Test
    public void testAddNamedEntityToExistingGroup() throws EntityValidationException {
        int neSize = ed.getAllNamedEntities().size();
        NamedEntityGroup neg = ed.getAllNamedEntityGroups().iterator().next();

        assertNotNull(neg);
        assertTrue(neg.getNamedEntities().size() == 0);
        em.detach(neg);

        NamedEntity n = new NamedEntity();
        n.setName("Hello");

        neg.addNamedEntity(n);
        n.setNamedEntityGroup(neg);

        n.setType(NamedEntityType.DEFAULT);

        ed.save(n);
        for(NamedEntity e : ed.getAllNamedEntities()) {
            L.error("Entity: {}", e);
        }

        assertTrue("Size is " + ed.getAllNamedEntities().size() + " but it should be " + (neSize + 1) + " the group has "
                + neg.getNamedEntities().size() + " entities (should be 1) " + ed.getAllNamedEntities(), neSize + 1 == ed.getAllNamedEntities().size());
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Entity: NamedEntity [id=1, name=Super Mario Brothers, namedEntityGroup=null, type=null]
Entity: NamedEntity [id=3, name=Mario Kart, namedEntityGroup=null, type=null]
Entity: NamedEntity [id=5, name=F-Zero, namedEntityGroup=null, type=null]
Entity: NamedEntity [id=7, name=Hello, namedEntityGroup=NamedEntityGroup [id=2, name=Super Mario Brothers, COUNT(entity)=1], type=DEFAULT]
Entity: NamedEntity [id=8, name=Hello, namedEntityGroup=NamedEntityGroup [id=2, name=Super Mario Brothers, COUNT(entity)=1], type=DEFAULT]
```

Id's `7` and `8` are duplicates in the output as the `save` method is inserting an item 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAO `save` method is ugly, refactor it, otherwise expect more issues like this one. :)

The issue is in the `em.merge(ne.getNamedEntityGroup())` in the DAO `save` method. Because `NamedEntityGroup` cascades `ALL` to `namedEntities`, `MERGE` is cascaded to the `ne` which is transient (unsaved), causing a **new** `NamedEntity` instance to be created. `ne` instance is removed from the `namedEntities` collection and a copy of it is placed in it. [Session.merge javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent
>   instance. **If the given instance is unsaved, *save a copy of* and
>   return it as a newly persistent instance.** The given instance does
>   not become associated with the session. This operation cascades to
>   associated instances if the association is mapped with cascade="merge".

Afterwards you persist the passed in `ne` as well, so you end up with two persisted `NamedEntity` instances: one created (copied) by `merge` and the one you explicitly persisted (`ne`).

The proper solution is to refactor `save` to something that does not contain the code like `if(!em.contains(ne.getNamedEntityGroup()))` and similar things.

The ugly quick fix is to remove the unnecessary `em.persist(ne)` from the `if` body. This will make the things work, but it will be very confusing (the passed in `ne` will still be transient after `save` returns).

A little better quick fix is to load the persistent `NamedEntityGroup`:

```
NamedEntityGroup group = em.getReference(NamedEntityGroup.class, ne.getNamedEntityGroup().getId());
ne.setNamedEntityGroup(group);
```

Comment: That's it, I could not put 2+2 together and realize the "save a copy of" was doing it.  Thank you.